# Angular CDK Drag&Drop: How to access CDK Drag Element from a HTMLElement?

Tags: angular, angular-cdk, angular-cdk-drag-drop

Is there a good way to access the `DragRef` if I e.g. `document.querySelector` the `HTMLElement` it's attached to?

This seems to work but seems less than ideal: `myHtmlElement.__ngContext__.directives[0]`

And `ng.getContext()` (https://angular.io/api/core/global/ngGetContext) is a different context altogether :)

I know I get the `DragRef` when I work with the events of the CDK (e.g. `CdkDragEnd`) but in my case I actually need to do something (specifically `.reset` it) with a different drag element than the one I currently drag & drop.

Thanks!

PS: storing the DragRefs in an array and retrieving them by somehow connecting them with their HTMLElements would be my other approach but I thought there might be a better way from the HTMLElement itself.